# Understanding how to use a Validation Loop in C++ (HELP)

Tags: c++, loops, validation

> Below is what I am trying to accomplish. My code works aside from the validation loop. Any help would be greatly appreciated!!

1. Refactor your code to divide all your tasks into functions.  Your variables can be declared in main or as local variables within the functions.  Pass in parameters as needed.  Do not declare global variables unless it's a constant.
2. The main program should contain a menu with at least 4 items including "quit" which calls these functions (your tasks) and loops until the user selects quit.  An Input validation loop should be included to validate the user's input for their menu selection.
3. Within the functions, there should be at least one decision structure either an if-then-else based condition or a switch statement.

   ```
   using namespace std;
   void DecimalToBinary(int n) {
       int binaryNumber[100], num = n;
       int i = 0;
       while (n > 0) {
           binaryNumber[i] = n % 2;
           n = n / 2;
           i++;
       }
       cout << "Binary form of " << num << " is ";
       for (int j = i - 1; j >= 0; j--)
           cout << binaryNumber[j];
       cout << endl;
   }
   int BinaryToDecimal(int n) {
       int decimalNumber = 0;
       int base = 1;
       int temp = n;
       while (temp) {
           int lastDigit = temp % 10;
           temp = temp / 10;
           decimalNumber += lastDigit * base;
           base = base * 2;
       }
       cout << "Decimal form of " << n << " is " << decimalNumber << endl;;
   }
   int main() {
       DecimalToBinary();
       BinaryToDecimal(10101);

       int choice;
       int input;

   do {
       cout << "Enter 1 to exit the program: \n";
       cout << "Enter 2 to enter a binary number: \n";
       cout << "Enter 3 to enter a decimal number: \n";
       cout << "Enter 4 to do something else: \n";
       cin >> input;
       switch (input) {
       case '1':
           choice = 1;
           break;
       case '2':
           choice = 1;
           break;
       case '3':
           choice = 1;
           break;
       case '4':
           choice = 1;
           break;
       default:
           choice = 0;
       }

   } while (choice);

   DecimalToBinary();
   BinaryToDecimal(10101);
   return 0;
   }
   ```

Comment: You probably mean `while (choice == 0)`

Answer (score 0):

```
int main() {

    int choice;
    int input;

do {
    cout << "Enter 1 to exit the program: \n";
    cout << "Enter 2 to enter a binary number: \n";
    cout << "Enter 3 to enter a decimal number: \n";
    cout << "Enter 4 to do something else: \n";
    cin >> input;
    switch (input) {
    case 1:
        choice = 0;
        break;
    case 2:
        int number;
        cout<<"Enter a binary number: ";
        cin>>number;
        cout<<endl;
        BinaryToDecimal(number);
        break;
    case 3:
        int decimalNumber;
        cout<<"Enter a decimal number:";
        cin>>decimalNumber;
        cout<<endl;
        DecimalToBinary(decimalNumber);
    case 4:
        choice = 1;
        break;
    default:
        choice = 0;
    }

} while (choice);

return 0;
}
```